# What's the max char size you can share via Android share

Tags: share-menu

With the colornote app for I have quite large docs (thousands of lines, not sure precise char count) so when I click 'send' on the largest ones to bring up the standard android share popup the pop-up never appears.

Is there a known limit on the size of the text to share?

Comment: I don't know if there is a limit but I have used direct share for voluminous text from she colour note app. Wonder, if it is related to free RAM. Clear all apps from recently by swiping and then try to see if it helps

Comment: Couldn't find anything limiting size. So that may not be the reason

Comment: Tried that - with 1.8 GB free there was still no popup. Did a copy/paste to a Google Doc instead.

Comment: Which means to me that it is an app limitation and not that of direct share